# Can a limit of form$\ \frac{0}{0}$ be rational if the numerator is the difference of transcendental functions, and the denominator a polynomial one?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Let$\ f_1(x)$ and$\ f_2(x)$ be transcendental functions such that$\ \lim_{x\to 0} f_1(x)-f_2(x)=0$, and$\ f_3(x) $ polynomial, such that$\ f_3(0)=0$. Can$\ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f_1(x)-f_2(x)}{f_3(x)}$ be rational?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f_3(0)\ne0$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f_1(x)-f_2(x)}{f_3(x)}=0\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$
The above example was given before the OP added the condition $f_3(0)=0$.

If you want something less trivial
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x}=1\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$

Comment: Ok, sorry,$\ f_3(0)=0$. I've made an edit.

Comment: I have added a new example.

Comment: I see, thank you. Might I ask: does this keep on being possible if we put the condition that the limit is between, say,$\ +1$ and$\ +2$?

Comment: A variation on the same example: $\lim_{x\to0}(e^{ax}-e^{bx})/x=a-b$. Choose $a,b$ such that $a-b\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 4):

A more boring example: Let $f$ be a transcendental function. Then $$\frac{(f(x)+x)-f(x)}{x}$$ works.

Comment: When looking at objects that lack some nice property (common examples of nice properties include rational numbers, continuous / differentiable functions) then this is the standard, boring way of constructing two distinct, "ugly" objects such that their difference _does_ have the nice property.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\sin x -(e^x-1)}{x^2} \to - \frac12
$$